# Show "Please wait for processing to complete" message when aspx page completes loading

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, dropdownbox

I have a aspx page with a gridview with multiple dropdowns on every row to select categories(almost looks similar to an excel sheet).Each time the user tries to insert a row to the gridview, I copy the grid's current values to a session and then create a empty row for the user to enter a new row. The user has option to save once they decide they have made all the entries necessary. There are times based on the selction on one of the grid value, multiple rows have to be automatically inserted.

Having said that loading between drop down selections inside a row in the gridview takes a bit of a time. I want to show the user that the page is loading and they have to wait instead of clicking something in the web app multilple times. Also i have to make sure the process keeps running without waiting for the user to click ok if a dialog message is display for the "Please wait" message. How can i do that?

I tried Jquery option in a page load event to alert a message. It's just for showing a message.

Second i tried thread.sleep(1000) but that just slows the experience. Already the loading takes 30 seconds or so.

My database is smaller, and i am only trying to display like 100 rows. but each row has 10 columns and those columns have dropdown boxes. based on whats selected in first column, second column shows up. also when specific values are selected in the first row, 10 child rows gets automatically created. Basically my post back is on the selected index changed event of each and every drop down. I could have used edititemtemplate for gridview, but i didnt think it will affect the performance since its just 100 rows.

Also there is an option to insert a row and i show an empty row with no dropdown options selected. But when insert a row in the gridview which has 20 rows already, i had to save the current values selected in each row and then rebind the grid with the saved values and then insert an empty row. I believe this operation is costly - save all the rows, rebind the gridview.. is this how it has to be done
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThlUo.png)

Comment: You have to show where, when, how and the code that causes that post-back. Without that code and how you trigger the post-back, we really can't help you. Also, even if your database is small and only say 1 million rows, any database operations should occure WELL under 1 second. So, it not clear why or what would take 30 seconds, but even when I say fill out a grid view and pull records from a table with 9 million rows, the gv fills in less than 1 second. So while you can display some please wait, you would be MUCH better to determine why such huge delays exist in your horrible designs.

Comment: There is a simple and easy example on how to show a please wait/loading of a gridview in this example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74136217/i-need-to-show-loading-message-in-asp-net-webforms/74143181?noredirect=1#comment130916518_74143181

Comment: My database is smaller, and i am only trying to display like 100 rows. but each row has 10 columns and those columns have dropdown boxes. based on whats selected in first column, second column shows up. also when specific values are selected in the first row, 10 child rows gets automatically created. Basically my post back is on the selected index changed event of each and every drop down.  I could have used edititemtemplate for gridview, but i didnt think it will affect the performance since its just 100 rows.

Comment: Also there is an option to insert a row and i show an empty row with no dropdown options selected. But when insert a row in the gridview which has 20 rows already, i had to save the current values selected in each row and then rebind the grid with the saved values and then insert an empty row. I believe this operation is costly - save all the rows, rebind the gridview.. is this how it has to be done?

Comment: updated my Original question to add a screenshot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need to show loading message in asp.net webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74136217/i-need-to-show-loading-message-in-asp-net-webforms)

Comment: no, i tried to do this, but onclientclick event is not firing up. I have a master page for this aspx page.. i tried this solution in a new applicaiton without master page it works.. is there something specific that i need to make it work for aspx page with master page

Comment: The link shared by Albert D. Kallal worked.. thank you so much. Is there a way to mark it as an answer?